# Change defaultModel inside onAfterRender

Tags: wicket

I have a `Panel` and a `Image` inside this `Panel`.
In `onAfterRender` I want to change the `defaultModel` of the `Image`.

```
@Override
protected void onAfterRender() {
    super.onAfterRender();

    previewImage.setDefaultModel(new Model<String>(newUrl));


}
```

But this has no effect. The purpose is to display a `placeholder` and when the `Panel` is rendered, then change its `src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onAfterRender()` is a callback executed right after the current `Component` has been rendered, i.e. it has contributed its part of the final HTML sent to the browser.

It is not very clear what you want to achieve with this placeholder.
In case you want to show a placeholder and then lazily load the real image then you can use `AjaxLazyLoadPanel` from wicket-extensions. Or you can use JavaScript to replace the placeholder once the image is loaded by the browser (`img.addEventListener('load', ...)`.

`onAfterRender()` is usually used to render something right after the content/body rendered by this Component, but it cannot be used to change it.

Comment: Yes it is true, but the Problem with the LazyLoadPanel is that for example Text is displayed first, which breaks the flow of the page. So I want to display the placeholder and the text and then start to download the image.

Comment: @greedsin if you know the image size you can style the `div` so it has similar dimensions?